# Windows 2012 r2 port forwarding

Tags: vpn, virtualbox, windows-server-2012-r2

So my problem is that I'm trying to open a Virtualbox RDP on Windows 2012 to VPN nework on the same host.
I've got one external network adapter and a virtual adapter, created by VPN.
I've set up a port forwarding 8888->3389 so that on the same server I'm able to open RDP on localhost:8888, externalIP:8888 and VPNIP:8888, but this port is not open to any of those networks from outside. I need to see it inside VPN.

I've turned off Windows Firewall totally and my hosting provider assured me he's put no firewall in front of server. What am I missing here?